# Not show adaptive card microsoft teams bot

Tags: python, office365, microsoft-teams

i wanna make microsoft teams bot send pdf file, but i have issue with displaying it. In the teams chat writing `"This card's content could not be displayed"` .
[image]

But if i try in azure for testing im getting info with file name but not showing download button or something like what
[image]

Message in chat

```
{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.consent",
  "content": {
    "description": "This is the file I want to send you",
    "sizeInBytes": 27374,
    "acceptContext": {
      "filename": "test.pdf"
    },
    "declineContext": {
      "filename": "test.pdf"
    }
  },
  "name": "test.pdf"
}
```

My teams code in python.

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        self._add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)
        if " send pdf" in  turn_context.activity.text:
            
            filename = "test.pdf"
            file_path = "C:/files/" + filename
            file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            await self._send_file_card(turn_context, filename, file_size)

        else:
            return await turn_context.send_activity(
                f"You sent : {turn_context.activity.text}"
                )

    async def _send_file_card(
            self, turn_context: TurnContext, filename: str, file_size: int
    ):
        """
        Send a FileConsentCard to get permission from the user to upload a file.
        """

        consent_context = {"filename": filename}

        file_card = FileConsentCard(
            description="This is the file I want to send you",
            size_in_bytes=file_size,
            accept_context=consent_context,
            decline_context=consent_context
        )

        as_attachment = Attachment(
            content=file_card.serialize(), content_type=ContentType.FILE_CONSENT_CARD, name=filename
        )

        reply_activity = self._create_reply(turn_context.activity)
        reply_activity.attachments = [as_attachment]
        await turn_context.send_activity(reply_activity)

    async def on_teams_file_consent_accept(
            self,
            turn_context: TurnContext,
            file_consent_card_response: FileConsentCardResponse
    ):
        """
        The user accepted the file upload request.  Do the actual upload now.
        """

        file_path = "C:/files/test.pdf"
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

        headers = {
            "Content-Length": f"\"{file_size}\"",
            "Content-Range": f"bytes 0-{file_size-1}/{file_size}"
        }
        response = requests.put(
            file_consent_card_response.upload_info.upload_url, open(file_path, "rb"), headers=headers
        )

        if response.status_code != 201:
            print(f"Failed to upload, status {response.status_code}, file_path={file_path}")
            await self._file_upload_failed(turn_context, "Unable to upload file.")
        else:
            await self._file_upload_complete(turn_context, file_consent_card_response)

    async def on_teams_file_consent_decline(
            self,
            turn_context: TurnContext,
            file_consent_card_response: FileConsentCardResponse
    ):
        """
        The user declined the file upload.
        """

        context = file_consent_card_response.context

        reply = self._create_reply(
            turn_context.activity,
            f"Declined. We won't upload file <b>{context['filename']}</b>.",
            "xml"
        )
        await turn_context.send_activity(reply)

    async def _file_upload_complete(
            self,
            turn_context: TurnContext,
            file_consent_card_response: FileConsentCardResponse
    ):
        """
        The file was uploaded, so display a FileInfoCard so the user can view the
        file in Teams.
        """

        name = file_consent_card_response.upload_info.name

        download_card = FileInfoCard(
            unique_id=file_consent_card_response.upload_info.unique_id,
            file_type=file_consent_card_response.upload_info.file_type
        )

        as_attachment = Attachment(
            content=download_card.serialize(),
            content_type=ContentType.FILE_INFO_CARD,
            name=name,
            content_url=file_consent_card_response.upload_info.content_url
        )

        reply = self._create_reply(
            turn_context.activity,
            f"<b>File uploaded.</b> Your file <b>{name}</b> is ready to download",
            "xml"
        )
        reply.attachments = [as_attachment]

        await turn_context.send_activity(reply)

    async def _file_upload_failed(self, turn_context: TurnContext, error: str):
        reply = self._create_reply(
            turn_context.activity,
            f"<b>File upload failed.</b> Error: <pre>{error}</pre>",
            "xml"
        )
        await turn_context.send_activity(reply)

    def _create_reply(self, activity, text=None, text_format=None):
        return Activity(
            type=ActivityTypes.message,
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            from_property=ChannelAccount(
                id=activity.recipient.id, name=activity.recipient.name
            ),
            recipient=ChannelAccount(
                id=activity.from_property.id, name=activity.from_property.name
            ),
            reply_to_id=activity.id,
            service_url=activity.service_url,
            channel_id=activity.channel_id,
            conversation=ConversationAccount(
                is_group=activity.conversation.is_group,
                id=activity.conversation.id,
                name=activity.conversation.name,
            ),
            text=text or "",
            text_format=text_format or None,
            locale=activity.locale,
        )
```

Any idea where i do wrong? in this [article](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Adaptive-card-not-displaying-action-button-Show-Card/td-p/500155) i found need set adaptive card i try it set on manifest.json and another files, but not working. My basic code for set teams bot send file was in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/56.teams-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I talk under correction, but to my knowledge you can't send an -actual- file in an Adaptive Card in Teams - you need to store the file elsewhere (e.g. SharePoint / Azure Blob), and simply send a *link* to the file in the Adaptive Card (or even regular Text message).